# How to avoid line breaks after ":before" in CSS

Tags: css, css-content

On my website I'm using font icons for certain link types. These icons are added via `:before` CSS syntax.

```
a.some-link:before {
  font-family: icons;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 0.3em;
  content: 'x';
}
```

However, when this link is at the beginning of a line, it's sometimes separated from its icon:

[image: Separated icon from link]

I tried adding `white-space: nowrap` to the CSS rule above but that didn't help.

**How do I keep the icon and the text together?** (CSS 3 is okay)

Note: I don't want to format the *whole* link with `white-space: nowrap`.

Comment: For those wondering why `white-space: nowrap;` doesn't work, it's because it only prevents the `::before` itself from wrapping. It does does not prevent a wrap between the `::before` and the subsequent element.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply removing the `display:inline-block;` seems to fix this issue:

```
a.some-link:before {
    font-family: icons;
    padding-right: 0.3em;
    content: 'x';
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MMbKK/).

Unfortunately, you need "display: inline-block" to show SVG. Simple solution is to put "display: inline-block" on the "a". This will cause your SVG to render properly AND it will keep your a:before and the a together on one line.

Comment: For the record, the reason this works is because if you remove the `inline-block` specification, it defaults to `inline`. Once considered inline it follows the current word-break rules as if your psuedo-element was just another letter in the sentence.

Answer (score 9):

It is much better to add `nowrap` rule to `:before` css:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

UPD: http://jsfiddle.net/MMbKK/5/

The reason for `nowrap` rule is to work properly with image content in `:before`. Text content don't need this rule to stay near the main element.

Comment: Any particular reason why this is better? you should detail your answer a bit more I think.

Comment: The OP specified they are not looking for a `nowrap` solution.

Comment: Uh, sorry, I am new to this community and didn't saw notification before.

`nowrap` inside `:before` CSS rule worked in my case. May be it was only in my main browser.

`a.tooltipWord:before {
 content: url('..../quest_min.gif');
 white-space: nowrap;
}`

Oh, I was not clear enough, I see it now. The point was to change `inline-block` rule to `nowrap` one, not to add them up.

Comment: Thank you, @m-patel :) I updated my comment with explanations.

Comment: This prevents the `::before` from wrapping, but does not prevent a wrap between the `::before` and the element.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to avoid wrapping between the anchor and :before would be:

```
a.some-link {
    display: inline-block;
}
a.some-link::before {
    content: 'x';
}
```

Bonus!
To avoid text-decoration underlining for :before on hover:

```
a.some-link::before {
    display: inline-block;
}
```